# Inverse of a function with a norm

Tags: calculus, general-topology, functions

I'm doing a topology exercise and our teacher wrote a solution, the thing is that in one step he tries to find the inverse of a function that works as an example.

The function is 
$f: x \rightarrow \frac{x}{1-\|x\|}$

being $\|x\|$ the norm of x.

He says that the inverse is 
$\frac{y}{1+\|y\|}$

I can't understand how, why is the norm of $\|y\|$ here?

Could you help me, please?

Thank you

Comment: In this case you can just check that the function $y \mapsto y/(1+||y||)$ is actually the inverse. You see that $$f(y/(1+||y||)) = \frac{y/(1+||y||)}{1 - ||y||/(1+||y||)} = \frac{y/(1+||y||)}{1/(1+||y||)} = y,$$ and similarly for the other direction.

Comment: More generally, how do you find the inverse of a function? You start with the equation $f(x) = y$, and you try to write $x$ as a function of $y$ (if $f$ is injective). In this case, you have $x/(1-||x||) = y$, which implies that $||y|| = ||x||/(1-||x||)$, and hence $1+||y|| = 1/(1-||x||)$ and the result follows.

Comment: Didn't think that you could do the f(inverse) thing, thanks. And yes, that was what I was trying to do,, the thing you said in the second comment but I couldn't manage to get the correct result. Thanks again.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think that you may be operating under the assumption that $\|x\| < 1$. The function $f$ takes some element $x$ to $y$, where $y = x / (1 - \| x\|)$. If we claim that the function $g$ that takes $x$ to $x / (1 + \|x\|)$ is the inverse, it just remains to show that composition of the functions gives the identity.

This is done by taking one function and applying the other on it (i.e. treat one function as the argument of the other). It can be verified that 
$$g(f(x)) = \frac{x / (1 - \|x\|)}{1 + \bigg|\bigg|\frac{x}{1 - \|x\|}\bigg|\bigg|} = \frac{x / (1 - \|x\|)}{1 + \|x\| / (|1 - \|x\||)} = \frac{x}{ (1 - \|x\|) + \|x\|} = x$$
Here we have used the fact that norms are multiplicative. It can be seen that the fact that $\|x\| < 1$ is important, as the denominator only simplifies if the sign of $1 - \|x\|$ is positive. You can similarly show that $f(g(x)) = 1$.